# SQL or EF core what and how is the easiest way of finding Target.Id based on Names in other tables

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

IM struggling finding a good way to resolve this target.ID.

I have a string with "Machine.name, Department.Name, Workgroup.Name, Resource.Name, Workplace.Name" and want what TargetID this is connected too.

I have access to EF core, but multiple solutions are welcome to help understand this.

[image]

Comment: It is just a linq WHERE query. _context.Workplace.Where(x=>x.Name == "Home").ToList();

Comment: @jdweng the issue i have are the 3 many to many in the middle what im doing now is lists and lotsa looping to compare but it seems so heavy.

Comment: Depends how often you do the operation.  If you are doing it a lot than make a dictionary for each table.  It takes time to create the dictionary, but the lookup will be very fast.  You already have the dictionary since it is a primary key.  So lookup by primary key : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/

Comment: @jdweng what question are you answering?

Comment: @insane_developer : To reduce the looping time.

Comment: Well, it's worth considering writing a SQL query for this and see how fast it performs, assuming the right indexes are in place, if there is a real need for them (maybe the tables are not that big?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now a query from one of my co workers

```
SELECT t.Id FROM Target t, TargetResource tr, TargetMachine tm, TargetWorkplace tw
WHERE t.Id = tr.TargetId 
AND t.Id = tm.TargetId 
AND t.Id = tw.TargetId
AND tr.ResourceId = (SELECT r.Id FROM Resource r WHERE Name = 'Res1' 
                        AND r.DepartmentId = (SELECT d.Id FROM Department d WHERE Name = 'D2')  
                        AND r.WorkgroupId = (SELECT w.Id FROM Workgroup w WHERE Name = 'WG4'))
AND tm.MachineId = (SELECT m.Id FROM Machine m WHERE Name = 'MaC2' 
                        AND m.DepartmentId = (SELECT d.Id FROM Department d WHERE Name = 'D2'))
AND tw.WorkplaceId = (SELECT w.Id FROM Workplace w WHERE Name = 'WorkP3')
```